# error: The requirement is only added

Tags: rust

I tried to compile the [fuse](https://crates.io/crates/fuse/0.2.5) crate.

This fails with the following error:

```
session.rs:110:1: 114:2 error: The requirement `FS : Filesystem` is added only by the Drop impl. [E0367]
```

The corresponding [line](https://github.com/zargony/rust-fuse/blob/master/src/session.rs#L110) looks like this:

```
impl<FS: Filesystem> Drop for Session<FS>
```

i.e. the `Drop` trait is implemented for the `Session` type, which looks fine to me.

What exactly is the error here?

Comment: Looks like [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/5b2e8693e42dee545d336c0364773b3fbded93a5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use conditional or multi dispatch for the `Drop` trait right now. In other words, each implementation of Drop has to apply to all "forms" of the `Self` type, and so can't have bounds on contained type parameters that aren't part of the type itself.

In this example, `Session<FS>` would only implement `Drop` if `FS: Filesystem`, but `Session<u8>` wouldn't. This is not allowed. To fix this error you can either remove the bound on the `Drop` impl or add `where FS: Filesystem` to the "inherent" bounds for the `Session` type by adding it at the type declaration.